# theos error "alertView was not declared in this scope"

Tags: objective-c, cydia, theos

I am making a tweak which changes some things in a game.
I am trying to hook with `OpenMenu` to make it display an alert asking if The user want to change revert the game back to normal or if the user wants to continue to settings

But at line 88: I'm always getting this error`alertView was not declared in this scope`

The codes are here

http://pastebin.com/Rz8PqG9p

Pls help me here, I did not have this erie when I didn't try to add another Alert

Comment: didn't you notice `(UIAlertView *)actionSheet` ? its not alertView.tag , use actionsheet.tag in that method! alertView is defined outside the scope of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the parameter is named **actionSheet** not alertView. I guess you can change that easily.

```
...
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ((alertView.tag == 1)) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {    
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I made such a mistake